# Mejorar tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me consulta distintos procesos en mi BD, pero al unirlos todos para ejecutarlos y traerlos en un reporte en Crystal Reports se demora unos 5-10 min en su tiempo de ejecucion, como puedo mejorar este tiempo?

```
--Ventas
SELECT MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) AS Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry, T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,
T1.WhsCode'Filler','VENTA'AS WhsCode,T1.ItemCode,T2.ItemName,T1.Quantity,T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,
((T1.Price-(T1.Price*T0.DiscPrcnt)/100)+(((T1.Price-(T1.Price*T0.DiscPrcnt)/100)*T1.VatPrcnt)/100))AS 'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM OINV T0 INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE T1.WhsCode='PB-PT' AND T2.ItemCode NOT IN ('IMP-00001','IMP-00002','SER-00001','SER-00002','SER-00003','SER-00004','SER-00005','SER-00006','CAN-14000','CAN-14025','CAN-14026','CAN-14072')
UNION ALL
--Notas Crédito-Articulo
SELECT MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) AS Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry, T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,
T1.WhsCode'Filler','VENTA'AS WhsCode,T1.ItemCode,T2.ItemName,CASE WHEN T1.NoInvtryMv='Y' THEN 0 ELSE T1.Quantity*-1 END AS'Quantity',T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,
((T1.Price-(T1.Price*T0.DiscPrcnt)/100)+(((T1.Price-(T1.Price*T0.DiscPrcnt)/100)*T1.VatPrcnt)/100))AS 'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM ORIN T0 INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE T1.WhsCode='PB-PT' AND T2.ItemCode NOT IN ('IMP-00001','IMP-00002','SER-00001','SER-00002','SER-00003','SER-00004','SER-00005','SER-00006','CAN-14000','CAN-14025','CAN-14026','CAN-14072')
UNION ALL
--Notas Crédito-Servicio
SELECT MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) AS Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry, T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,
'PB-PT'AS'Filler','VENTA'AS WhsCode,T1.[U_ItemCodeSer],T1.Dscription'ItemName',1*-1'Quantity',T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,
((T1.Price-(T1.Price*T0.DiscPrcnt)/100)+(((T1.Price-(T1.Price*T0.DiscPrcnt)/100)*T1.VatPrcnt)/100))AS 'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM ORIN T0 INNER JOIN RIN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
            -- INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE T0.Doctype='S' AND T1.OcrCode2 IN ('2501032','2501')
UNION ALL
--Traslados PV
SELECT MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) as Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry, 
T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,T0.Filler,T1.WhsCode,T1.ItemCode,T2.ItemName,T1.Quantity,T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,T1.Price'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM OWTR T0 INNER JOIN WTR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE T0.Filler='PB-PT' AND T1.WhsCode like 'PV-%'
UNION ALL
--Traslados PDC
SELECT  MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) as Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry, T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,T1.WhsCode'Filler',CASE WHEN T1.WhsCode='PB-PT' THEN 'PDC-MPC' ELSE 'PB-PT' END AS WhsCode,
T1.ItemCode,T2.ItemName,T1.Quantity,T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,T1.Price'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM OIGE T0 INNER JOIN IGE1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE (T1.WhsCode='PB-PT' AND T0.U_Concepto_INVE='S006') OR
       (T1.WhsCode='PB-PT'  AND T0.U_Concepto_INVE='S005') 
UNION ALL
SELECT MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) as Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry, 
T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,T0.Filler,T1.WhsCode,T1.ItemCode,T2.ItemName,T1.Quantity,T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,T1.Price'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM OWTR T0 INNER JOIN WTR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE T0.Filler='PB-PT' AND T1.WhsCode like 'PDC-%'
UNION ALL
--Devouliciones PV
SELECT  MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) as Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry, T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,T1.WhsCode'Filler',T0.Filler'WhsCode',T1.ItemCode,T2.ItemName,T1.Quantity*-1 as 'Quantity',T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,T1.Price'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM OWTR T0 INNER JOIN WTR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE T1.WhsCode='PB-PT' AND T1.WhsCode like 'PV-%'
UNION ALL
--Entrada PDC
SELECT  MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) as Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry,T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,T1.WhsCode'Filler',CASE WHEN T1.WhsCode='PB-PT' THEN 'PDC-MPC' ELSE 'PB-PT' END AS WhsCode,
T1.ItemCode,T2.ItemName,T1.Quantity*-1,T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,T1.Price'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM OIGN T0 INNER JOIN IGN1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE (T1.WhsCode='PB-PT' AND T0.U_Concepto_INVE='E006') OR
       (T1.WhsCode='PB-PT'  AND T0.U_Concepto_INVE='E005')
UNION ALL
SELECT  MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS Mes,YEAR(T0.DocDate) as Ano,T0.Objtype,CAST(T0.DocEntry AS CHAR )AS DocEntry, T0.DocNum,T0.DocDate,T1.WhsCode'Filler',T0.Filler'WhsCode',T1.ItemCode,T2.ItemName,T1.Quantity*-1 as 'Quantity',T1.Quantity AS Cantidad,T1.Price'Precio Admistrativo',T1.StockPrice'Costo Real'
FROM OWTR T0 INNER JOIN WTR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T2.ItemCode=T1.ItemCode
WHERE T1.WhsCode='PB-PT' AND T1.WhsCode like 'PDC-%'
```

este informe es generado por hora, por lo cual quisiera que generara un poco mas rapido para asi evitar frenar otros procesos de produccion, aparte el informe es generado por varias personas a la vez por lo cual tambien afecta a la BD, ya que son varias consultas constantes que no tienen la mejor optimizacion

Comment: Este reporte tiene parametros? todas las tablas tienen nueva informacion durante el periodo de hora ? o consultan registros del dia anterior?

Comment: Hola Kevin, como punto de partida analiza tu consulta con el plan de ejecución y sus estadísticas. Esto te dará una mejor visión en donde posiblemente se encuentren tus cuellos de botella. quizás el siguiente ejemplo te pueda ser útil https://www.sqlshack.com/es/seguimiento-y-optimizacion-de-consultas-utilizando-indices-sql-server/

Comment: Miguel, todas las tablas se actualizan en cada hora, ya que estas son las que manejan la informacion de ventas, devoluciones, traslados etc, por lo cual la informacion siempre es constante en estas tablas

Comment: @Esteban Voy a validar con el plan de ejecucion a ver si me da algun indicio del problema, muchas gracias

Comment: La consulta no tiene ninguna indicación de algún problema en el código. Por favor, aparte del plan de ejecución, comparte las definiciones de las tablas e índices, así como un conteo aproximado de las filas de cada una.

Comment: Sugiero incluir más información sobre tus tablas, por ejemplo, la cantidad de registros, índices, particiones, y también el plan de ejecución de la consulta actual. De otra forma, no hay manera de responder la pregunta con precisión. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado te sugiero crear una tabla donde insertes el resultado de cada uno de los script sql y el reporte lo enlazas con dicha tabla, es mas optimo leer una tabla desde crystal report que ejecutar un script, no olvides hacer un truncate de la tabla antes de insertar los datos actualizados.

Comment: Muy bien, has añadido más pasos a la consulta (crear la tabla, llenar la tabla, leer la tabla). ¿Por qué crees que sería más rápido hacer eso? ¿Cómo aseguras que la información estará correctamente actualizada?

Comment: Estimado Luis, "dividir para conquistar" recuerda esta frase. Respecto de tu comentario puedo decir que, la creacion de tabla sólo la realizará 1 vez, y de esta forma es mucho más rápido, que usar sentencias UNION ALL. Saludos

Comment: Conozco la frase, pero en este caso dudo que pueda hacer una diferencia. UNION ALL sólo concatena los resultados. Incluso sería más eficiente para generar un `minimally logged INSERT` que incrementará la velocidad de inserción en una tabla vacía. Si la creación de la tabla sólo se realiza una vez, el TRUNCATE se ejecutará contínuamente, lo cual sería equivalente. Si puedes respaldar tus afirmaciones con pruebas, te invito a que lo hagas. Con la información que dio el OP no me atrevería a asegurar nada.

Comment: Pues no es tan malo lo de la tabla, si el reporte lo necesita cada hora puede correr una tarea que actualice en dicha tabla el reporte con los datos agregados desde su ultima actualizacion.

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi humilde opinión, si es que cuentas con acceso/permiso en la base de datos. Lo ideal seria crear indices sobre las columnas donde se apliquen filtro (where) o columnas que se usen el los joins.
La consulta se ejecutara mucho más rápido y con una carga de CPU muy inferior. Magia!!

Y con respecto a complejidad, no debes modificar ninguna consulta ni desarrollado ya realizado.
Podrías empezar con los siguientes columnas

```
Tabla/Columna
OINV.DocEntry
INV1.DocEntry
OITM.ItemCode
INV1.ItemCode
RIN1.DocEntry
WTR1.DocEntry
IGE1.WhsCode
OIGE.U_Concepto
IGN1.DocEntry
```

Saludos

Comment: Crear índices con una sola columna generaría una serie de `key lookups` en el plan de ejecución, lo cual es bastante costoso. Sería importante definir si son clustered o nonclustered, si son únicos o no y cuales columnas podrían ser incluidas para evitar los key lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy común en el uso de SSRS y Crystal Report que las consultas en el SSMS sean veloces y al utilizarlas en estos reportes se ralenticen debido a los planes de ejecución adicionales que se generan por los parametros, esto no se resuelve con indices ya que son dinámicos, pero la solución esta en eliminar estos planes de ejecución al ejecutarlos desde los reportes, para ello te recomiendo no colocar directamente la consulta en el reporte, sino una llamada a un SP, en el sp tienes 2 opciones colocar el OPTION(RECOMPILE) luego de la select:

```
SELECT A, B
    FROM Tabla
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B
    FROM Tabla2
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

La segunda opción es prevenir todo el plan de ejecución para variables en el procedimiento almacenado de la siguiente manera:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SSRS_Report]
   WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 1
END
```

Cualquier duda nos consultas a la comunidad. Y de haber solucionado tu incidencia no olvides calificar la respuesta.

Comment: Voy a probar con tu comentario, te estare comentando!

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que suelo hacer para mi aplicación es generar las consultas necesarias, (algún procedimiento almacenado), luego todos esos resultados los paso a un XML, posteriormente leo ese xml en el crystalreports. Y bueno, me funciona de maravilla.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/338771)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).